# Child Stateless Functional Component doesn't update even after parent State updates

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My parent component has a property in its state called `formIsValid`, initially set to false. My form also has a submit button. I want the submit button to be disabled until after some input fields (a first name and a last name input) have data in them.

This is what my state looks like:

```
  state = {
    employees: [],
    costEstimates: emptyCosts(),
    relationshipOptions: [],
    newEmployee: emptyEmployee(),
    formIsValid: false
  };
```

This function handles changes to the First and Last name inputs:

```
  // handle input into "First Name" and "Last Name" inputs
  handleChangeValue = async e => {
    const newEmployee = { ...this.state.newEmployee };
    newEmployee[e.currentTarget.name] = e.currentTarget.value;

    this.setState({ newEmployee });

    this.validateIfCanBeSubmitted();

    await this.updateCostsData(newEmployee); // this is an api thing, not relevent
  };
```

This is what sets the `formIsValid` property in the state. This property is sent as a prop to the Submit button.

```
  validateIfCanBeSubmitted = () => {
    const { firstName, lastName } = this.state.newEmployee;

    let formIsValid = firstName && lastName ? true : false;

    this.setState({ formIsValid });
  };
```

The Submit button for this is correctly getting disabled if the employee property in the state has its first and last names as empty. The problem is that it's "off by 1 update." It's as if the props aren't getting propagated down to the child button component until after the NEXT time the state changes. Here's a gif of the issue:

[image]

This is what the child component looks like. It's just a regular HTML button, however it's within a Stateless Functional Component, so the issue is not with the component's state:

```
    <button
      type="button"
      onClick={onSubmit}
      className={'btn btn-primary mr-1 ' + (formIsValid ? '' : 'disabled')}
      disabled={!formIsValid}
    >
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setState()` is asynchronous! 
`this.validateIfCanBeSubmitted();` is executed on the old state; this update `this.setState({ newEmployee });` has not been propagated to `this.state` when your function is executed.

Make `validateIfCanBeSubmitted` an update-function.

```
validateIfCanBeSubmitted = ({ newEmployee: { firstName, lastName }}) => {
  return {
    formIsValid: firstName && lastName ? true : false
  };
}
```

and use it accordingly:

```
handleChangeValue = async e => {
  const {name, value} = e.currentTarget;
  const newEmployee = { 
    ...this.state.newEmployee, 
    [name]: value
  };

  this.setState({ newEmployee });
  this.setState(this.validateIfCanBeSubmitted);

  // this is an api thing, not relevant
  await this.updateCostsData(newEmployee); 
};
```

Actually, the code in `handleChangeValue` should also be in such a function, as it uses the previous state to compute the new one.

so how about combining them:

```
handleChangeValue = e => {
  const {name, value} = e.currentTarget;
  this.setState((state) => {
    const newEmployee = { 
      ...this.state.newEmployee, 
      [name]: value
    };
    const { firstName, lastName } = newEmployee;
    const formIsValid = firstName && lastName ? true : false;

    //and since you never use the returned Promise, why make anything async?
    this.updateCostsData(newEmployee);

    return { newEmployee, formIsValid  };
  });
};
```

Comment: I didn't know setState was asynchronous. That explains a lot, thank you. I have a question: I tried doing `await this.setState({ newEmployee })` and that actually seems to have solved my issue. Is there any reason I shouldn't just await setState() ?

Comment: @Andrio please check that again. I know that setState takes a callback-function as a second argument, I've never heard that it returns a Promise. In the Docs I don't see that documented either, and in a quick test `setState()` returned `undefined`. So please check wether this is some undocumented behaviour and you really get that Promise *(so that you can use await)* or wether this was just coincidental that it worked.

Comment: putting `await` in front of it definitely fixed the problem for me; I did nothing else.

Comment: @Andrio just know, if `setState`does not return a Promise, then this "fix" is merely coincidental and it may fail when there is enough load on the computer during this task; or with any React update.